# Uniqueness of Seifert graphs

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology, surfaces, knot-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

If we make the bands and disks of a Seifert surface really small and really thin the surface collapses to a graph. It is called a Seifert graph.

1. If it is not a directed and weighted graph, can we say that for every unique Seifert graph there is a Seifert surface and vice versa?
2. If it is not a directed but weighted graph, can we say that for every unique Seifert graph there is a Seifert surface and vice versa?
3. If it is a both directed and weighted graph, can we say that for every unique Seifert graph there is a Seifert surface and vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regards to your first question, I will assume that you are taking your Seifert graph to be embedded in $\mathbb R^3$. This can correspond to multiple Seifert surfaces by taking any Seifert surface with this graph and then adding lots of full twists into one of the bands. I am not sure what you expect the weights and directions to mean for the Seifert surface, so I am not sure how to respond to questions 2 and 3.

Comment: Yes, the Seifert graph is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Let's say, we are always considering the Seifert surface of minimum genus. What are the answers to the questions 1 & 2 for minimum genus Seifert surfaces? Regarding the weights, we can consider +1 weight for an edge related to the  overcrossing and -1 weight for an edge related to the undercrossing in the knot from which the Seifert surface is generated. I am not sure whether the idea of direction is relevant here.

Comment: No doubt Jim knows better than I, but is the minimal genus Seifert surface of a link unique up to ambient isotopy?

Comment: @DanielRust, yes. But I am asking about Seifert graphs. Are they unique too?

Comment: @DanielRust: nope, it's not, but I don't know a reference off the top of my head.

Comment: @OmarShehab: Based on your comment, I see that you are thinking of Seifert surfaces as being related to a particular planar diagram of a knot. Is that true?

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip, yes.